# Bulk insert vs loop in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql

Apart from bulk insert to be faster in procedure vs using while loop inside procedure.

Does using while loop in procedure to make multiple insert have any disadvantage (deadlock?)
How both compare? I could not find proper explanation that which out of 2 should be used and when.

**While loop in proc**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SaveLog`(
     _totalcount           int (11),
     _eventType            varchar (20),
      _resumeDID            TEXT
 )
 BEGIN
     DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
     DECLARE element text;

    WHILE counter <=  _totalcount DO
    set  element = SPLIT(_resumeDID, counter);
     INSERT INTO `ProfilLog`
    (`EventType`, `ResumeDID`, `CreatedOn`)
    VALUES(_eventType, element, NOW());
    SET counter = counter + 1;
    END WHILE;
 END
```

split function

```
CREATE FUNCTION `Split`(
  x     VARCHAR(1000),
  pos   INT
) RETURNS varchar(1000) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
BEGIN
    RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, ',', pos), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, ',', pos -1)) + 1), ',', '');
END
```

Vs
**Bulk insert**

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `SaveLog`(
       _resumeDIDobj          TEXT
 
  )  BEGIN
 
      INSERT INTO `ProfilLog`   (`EventType`, `ResumeDID`, `CreatedOn`)     VALUES([[_resumeDIDobj]]);
      END
```

Comment: Mysql does not have SPLIT and bulk insert code is syntactically invalid.. Is this question tagged correctly. Please add sample date and desired outcome as text.

Comment: @P.Salmon updated the code to include split function and bulk insert code is for example

Comment: If you have to split then bulk insert is not an option..

Comment: i just want to know if deadlock occurs when using while loop inside procedure 
@P.Salmon

Comment: Are the `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` statements inside the SP or outside?  Or are you just using `autocommit=ON`?

Comment: Using autocommit on @RickJames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `autocommit=ON`, each write statement (such as your `INSERTs`) incurs some extra overhead of performing 'ACID' stuff.

Each roundtrip from between client and server has overhead.  This overhead is slightly less when coming from a Stored Procedure since it is on the same machine.  If the client and server are in different locations, the network lag can add a lot -- to each SQL statement (write or read).

`INSERTing` 100 rows in a single `INSERT` statement is literally 10 times as fast as 100 single-row `INSERTs`.

As for deadlocks, sure, a multirow action has more chance of a deadlock.  But are you really doing things that conflict with each other?  Most applications never run the risk of deadlocks simply because two clients are never working with the same row(s).

Also, battling `INSERTs` tend to hit "lock_wait_timeout" instead of "deadlock".  This is where InnoDB can clearly see that the best solution is to have one client stall waiting for the other to finish.  No errors, no deadlocks, all is good.

Your particular `INSERT` seems quite safe -- simply adding a 3-column row to a table?  No `UNIQUE` keys to conflict on?  No counter to bump?  Not an Upsert (IODKU)?  No obvious `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but that probably does not matter.  Again, probably the worst your multi-row `INSERT` will encounter is "lock_wait_timeout";m meanwhile, the tasks will get finished much faster by batching.